# ¿Cómo hago para que me imprima un solo resultado y no dos? en ASP .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, razor, loops, controller

Estoy haciendo un sistema de facturación. Me encuentro desarrollando la vista de editar venta, ya tengo un agregar venta al 100%. En la vista de "Listado de Ventas" quiero que al momento de darle click en "Editar" obtenga el código de la venta y lo mande a la vista "Edit" con el fin de mostrar los datos de la venta y el detalle (que los tengo en una sola entidad llamada "AuxiliarEntity"). Por eso es que primero quiero obtener los datos de la misma con un input; colocando el COD_VEN( que es int ) para poder setear los datos en la vista y manipularlos.
En este caso obtengo el RUC por ejemplo, pero me setea dos RUC que significa que tengo dos detalles en la misma venta. Pero solo quiero que setee un único RUC. ¿Cómo lo haría?

```html
<h2>Edit</h2>

<p>
  @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  <b>Ingrese una venta : </b>
  <input type="text" name="VEN_COD" />
  <input type="submit" value="Consultar" /> }
</p>


<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>
      RUC
    </th>
  </tr>

</table>

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.factura) {
<tr>
  <td>
    @item.RUC
  </td>
</tr>



//POR CADA DETALLE BOTA UN RUC }
```

y el controlador

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? VEN_COD)
    {
        List<AuxiliarEntity> l = new List<AuxiliarEntity>();
        l = venta.listarAuxiliarBL();

        ViewBag.factura = l.Where(p => p.VEN_COD == VEN_COD);

        return View();
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta te fue de utilidad?

Answer (score 0):

Se haría de la siguiente manera, sin embargo te recomiendo hacer un if en caso de que la consulta tenga 0 resultados.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? VEN_COD)
    {
        List<AuxiliarEntity> l = new List<AuxiliarEntity>();
        l = venta.listarAuxiliarBL();

        var factura = l.Where(p => p.VEN_COD == VEN_COD);
        ViewBag.factura = factura[0];


        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? VEN_COD)
{
    List<AuxiliarEntity> l = new List<AuxiliarEntity>();
    l = venta.listarAuxiliarBL();
    ViewBag.factura = l.Where(p => p.VEN_COD == VEN_COD).Distinct();
    return View();
}
```

El Distinct trabaja igual que en SQL, te trae sólo los records únicos de acuerdo a lo que selecciones.